# IUPAC name of the following bicyclic / spiro compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

We have the given compound
[image]

It's IUPAC naming is more sinister than things seem.

It's not a proper bicyclic compound, or a proper spiro cpmpound either.

[image]

I could interpret the spiro compound in red, though I doubt it does much, as well as the $-CHO$ functional group to be the special suffix, carbaldehyde, but not much else. It seems very odd to have a spiro compound, inside a bicyclic compound, making this compound feel very awkward.

Is this a tricyclic compound? If so, what is it's IUPAC name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IUPAC name is tricyclo[6.2.0.0<sup>1,4</sup>]decane-5-carbaldehyde. In general, for complex structures like this the IUPAC name is automatically generated, usually using software like ChemDraw or ChemAxon.